# Assigning multiple values in a parameter of Execute Sql task --SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am creating an `SSIS` package which uses `Execute sql task` and `Script task.` this package displays table contents based on the parameter.

I gave below query in the execute-sql task

```
 Select * from Production.Product Where ProductID in ( 316,324)
```

I need to assign the values `316, 324` into a `parameter` and populate result-set. how to assign multiple values in a p`arameter variable`? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have less than 2000 values in your CSV list - you can create a String variable Params with value `316, 324` and another String Variable SQL_Select with the following expression:

```
"Select * from Production.Product Where ProductID in ("+@[User::Params]+")"
```

In your *Execute Task* select variable as a query source and define User::SQL_Select as the source. Expression will be evaluated as you access it, and will yield the select statement.

Comment: thanks. but i wonder what happens if csv list is more than 2000? is it a limitation of ssis?

Comment: @bmsqldev, it is a limitation of MS SQL. It can handle no more than 2100 params, which means that in a SELECT query you can have no more than 2099 constants or values, 1 param is a query text itself. I roughly downsized it to 2000 in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @String nvarchar(Max),@ProductID varchar(25)

SET @productID ='316,324'

SET @String=''
SET @String='Select * from Production.Product Where ProductID in ( '+@productID+')  '
Print @String  
EXECUTE (@String)
```